# My FragmentPagerAdapter class's constructor is not getting defined in my main activity

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter, swipeview

I'm trying to implement a Swipe View with Tabs app but my adapter is giving an error. The constructor function is not getting defined in my Main Activity. I have used  the getSupportFragmentManager() function as the argument and all my files are .support.v4.app ones.

This is the code for my adapter. Please note I have not defined the fragments yet.

```
package com.example.tabpractice;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    switch (arg0) {
    case 0:        
        return new Fragment1();
    case 1:
        return new Fragment2();
    case 2:
        return new Fragment3();
    case 3:
        return new Fragment4();
        break;
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {     
    return 4;
}

}
```

And this is the code for my Main Activity

```
package com.example.tabpractice;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public abstract class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener{

ViewPager vPager;
TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
ActionBar actionBar;
String[] tabs = {"Home","Income","Expense","Transactions"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vPager.setAdapter(null);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    for(String tab_name : tabs){
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }



}
```

Comment: You forget to instantiate the `TabsPagerAdapter`, instead of `TabsPagerAdapter(...);` try to use `new TabsPagerAdapter(...);` and why you don't use `AppCompat v7` `ActionBarActivity` and use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`?

Comment: @Wakim Thanks! I'm new to this and I forgot to add the new! About the ActionBar, I'm not exactly sure about what you are suggesting I do. If you could post a link that would be helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: Take a look at this link, its make reference to the `AppCompat v7` library, which includes a support `ActionBar` to be used on Android below SDK 11. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

You forget to instantiate the `TabsPagerAdapter`, instead of `TabsPagerAdapter(...);` try to use `new TabsPagerAdapter(...);`